# Shadow around map / area

Tags: html, css, dictionary, shadow, area

I'm currently using a map with an area in it. I would like to have shadow around the map / area, although I have no idea how to do so.

```
<map name="map_bottom">
    <area id="area_bottom" shape="poly" coords="0,0,0,37,652,358,935,358,935,179,108,0" href="#" alt="" />
</map>
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

around the map , you can use box shadow but , on img tag.

To style map and area is possible in few browser (not Firefox ), set display:something you see..
example : http://dabblet.com/gist/5592972 &  http://dabblet.com/gist/5586117 (see map,area styled in opera, chrome nsome safaris).
An online tool can help you create your map. it produces the map code and css and html regular code , faking an area map .
http://www.image-maps.com/ , the code given needs to be clean . maybe there is others much better/easier.

Comment: Could you try to eloborate your answer as I don't understand it. I already have an map with an area in it, I just want to place shadow around that area.

Comment: to set shadow around area , you need display:block and position absolute on map and area.inside a relative container. then set the good coordinates for the area add box-shadow to it.IE, FF won't show anything. Did you dig a bit in the links i gave you and noticed you could import your map to produce html&css to use instead ?